# GoogleApiClient cant connect to API

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-client

I m trying to test my first google Api app. I m using google play service client lib to connect to google+ API. I made a simple connection, After I run it in my genymotion 4.4.4 (includes google app), a toast message says- "an internal error occurs", The logcat shows no error either.I added the permission for internet,accounts and credential in manifest.I integrated the SHA1 and project package well in console, added the meta data for play service version etc as in [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started),added  compile '**com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.87**' in gradle.
I m using android studio latest.
 THis is my code-

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
           private GoogleApiClient mClient;
        // Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
        private boolean mResolvingError = false;



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create a GoogleApiClient instance for google+
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mResolvingError) {  
            mClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // this shows a string log message but it shows nothing
        L.m(" I M CONNECTED");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
// this shows a string log message AND IT SHOWS UP
        L.m(" I M NOT CONNECTED");  
    }


}
```

This is my console (its just a test app, so nothing to hide)
[image]

Comment: This usually happens  when you haven't set the signature for the `client ID` in your `API console` project or if you used wrong key value from `keytool`. So check if you have filled all neccessary fields correctly in `Developer Console`

Comment: thnk u but what could go wrong with my console,see the picture of my console. I got the SHA1 in debug mode. package name is also ok... what can be the problem. Pls help

Comment: Check `API&AUTHS` section too and double check `SHA1` and `CliendID`

Comment: don't test in emulator.test in real device.

Comment: bro wat is this emulator.test, never heard of it ..  :P

Comment: you enabled the google+ api correct?

Comment: google+ api Enabled at the beginning

Comment: The ConnectionResult says statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED but there is NO SIGN IN procedure mentioned in Google Api Doc for acquiring GoogleApiClient,Yet I followed all the steps described in google play service doc to get the AUTH2 Token as mentioned, though I dont know what is the use of this token to make GoogleApiClient . Nevertheless, the ConnectionResult still says statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I changed the default location of my .android a long ago and there are two OS in my PC with two Android studio. Hence, I found that I was getting the certificate from the WRONG debug keystore. Sigh!! I wasted 3 days for this ... but for those of whom who may not have the same issue, check the consent screen in ur google console tab, see if product name and email address are mentioned. It may also result in the same error.